# How do I subset a box-plots in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

[image: Boxplot of Cylinders vs Economy_highway]

The code I used to get this boxplot from the "Cars" data is as follows:

```
boxplot(Economy_highway ~ Cylinders,data = Cars, main="Box Plot",ylab="cylinders", xlab="highway_economy",horizontal=TRUE, col = "skyblue")
```

My question is, how do we subset the cylinders 4 & 6 vs Economy_highway?

I have tried several subsetting codes but still unsuccessful.

Comment: `boxplot` has a `subset=` option, so, with a reproducible example you can do something like:  `boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars, subset=cyl %in% c(4,6))`

Comment: > boxplot(Economy_highway ~ Cylinders,data = Cars,subset=Cylinders %in% c(4,6), main="Box Plot", ylab="cylinders", xlab="highway_economy",horizontal=TRUE, col = "skyblue")

Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boxplot` has a `subset=` argument, so, with a reproducible example you can do something like:

```
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars, subset=cyl %in% c(4,6))
```

Which I think for your full example translates to:

```
boxplot(Economy_highway ~ Cylinders,data = Cars,subset=Cylinders %in% c(4,6), main="Box Plot", ylab="cylinders", xlab="highway_economy",horizontal=TRUE, col = "skyblue")
```